# How to get a Network's WIFI Password through CMD?

Tags: passwords, network, windows, wifi

I found that Wifi's Password can be retrived using the network and sharing wizard in Windows, And Technicaly theres no way to store Passwords/collection of bytes in the memory after switching/shutting down your computer, and So the Network and Sharing Wizard is also an application, and it has to store the password any way, so it saves the password in the disk, so there must be a way in which i can get the password using CMD, or if not with CMD where can i get that key, I'm trying to learn hacking my Wifi system, I use c++, with Win32 and i dont need any other libray than win32, I will implement command shell in my application, im doing this just for a knowledge about windows computer security, So is there anyone reading this question tells the way using the command prompt to get the Wirless Network/Wifi Password? Or any other way in which i can get that key in my application even through parsing a system file/searching in registry(for example) or any thing, i can even be happier if i got the WPA/PSK encrypted key if not the ascii version of the key, Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows stores these encrypted in the following locations:

> In Windows XP, wireless keys are stored in the Registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WZCSVC\Parameters\Interfaces\[Interface Guid]`. The [Interface Guid] is a unique GUID value the represents your wireless network card. The keys are well-encrypted by Windows operating system, so you cannot watch them with RegEdit.
>
> In Windows Vista, wireless keys are stored in the file system under `c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Wlansvc\Profiles\Interfaces\[Interface Guid]`. The [Interface Guid] is a unique GUID value the represents your wireless network card. The keys are stored and well-encrypted inside the .xml files that you can find in the above path.

Via [Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_wep_key_faq.html)

Comment: Thanks for your interest for answering but can u tell me where can i find it in win7 and win8? as creating programs only for older versions of windows are not getting highlighted as people prefer new Operating systems, i want to walk with the world, i currently checked both the options on a Win8 PC, and can't see any of them, is this because the PC im using is completely offline?? and why this happen that the keys are saved as encrypted? as in the Network and sharing wizard the password can be shown clearly as ASCII Text, where does the Network and Sharing Application stores it? thank u...

Comment: It's at the same location on Vista, 7, and 8. As long as your PC has saved a wifi password, it will contain something in that location - so its contents won't be affected by the fact that you are currently offline. Since ProgramData is a hidden folder, when browsing to that location make sure you have your view set to show hidden folders. Look up CryptUnprotectData - it will help you unencrypt the password.

Comment: Now, speculatively: the reason for encryption would be the same as for any stored password. And, I imagine the reason to allow it to be shown in plaintext is that sometimes convenience wins over pure security.

Comment: that means every time we request Network and sharing wizard to show characters, it decrypts the key?? there must be way to retrive the ASCII key, however u said the fact "Currently offline" will not effect any of them files/hives I does'nt mean by "CURRENTLY" i Meaned Completly offline, the computer which im using for testing has'nt ever connected to any wifi, so i can go only to "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\" there's no such 'wlansvc' folder in the folder "Microsoft", maybe i should check the computer connected to wifi even once?? Thanks for the help!!

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. You can, using CryptUnprotectData. Search this online and it will be clear how to use the wlansvc XML files to do so. 3. If the PC has never connected to any wireless network, it will not have any passwords stored. Passwords are only stored in wlansvc once you have connected once and chosen to remember the network. Why (indeed, how?) would there be an encrypted password there if no connection has ever been made?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/678812/how-to-view-wifis-password-or-forget-this-network-in-windows-8-1